# Cannot add picture to article - No driver specified

Tags: graphics, article

I am trying to type a straightforward document using `article` class.

```
\documentclass[12pt, english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{accents}
\DeclareMathAccent{\wtilde}{\mathord}{largesymbols}{"65}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.50\textwidth]{cm2.pdf}
        \label{fig:cm2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

On compiling, I get an error message

```
Package graphics error:No driver specified
```

How can I fix this? This is the resulting log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.3.22)  21 NOV 2016 09:32
entering extended mode
**trial.tex
(C:\Users\Remesh\LateX\tex\MISC.DOCS\trial.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, arabic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali
, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, galic
ian, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, icelandic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian,
 kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, ngerman
-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, sloven
ian, spanish, swedish, swissgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usenglishmax, w
elsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen103
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen104
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count87
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count88
\leftroot@=\count89
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
\classnum@=\count90
\DOTSCASE@=\count91
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen105
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
\macc@depth=\count92
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count93
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count94
\dspbrk@lvl=\count95
\tag@help=\toks15
\row@=\count96
\column@=\count97
\maxfields@=\count98
\andhelp@=\toks16
\eqnshift@=\dimen106
\alignsep@=\dimen107
\tagshift@=\dimen108
\tagwidth@=\dimen109
\totwidth@=\dimen110
\lineht@=\dimen111
\@envbody=\toks17
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks19
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)

! Package graphics Error: No driver specified.

See the graphics package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.89      }

You should make a default driver option in a file 
graphics.cfg
eg: \ExecuteOptions{textures}

)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen112
\Gin@req@width=\dimen113
) (C:\Users\Remesh\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\bezos\accents.sty
Package: accents 2006/05/12 v1.3 Math Accent Tools
\cc@skew=\dimen114
\cc@wd=\dimen115
\cc@code=\count99
\cc@group=\count100
\cc@skewchar=\count101
)

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [english].

(C:\Users\Remesh\LateX\tex\MISC.DOCS\trial.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.


! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .pdf.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 ...udegraphics[width=0.50\textwidth]{cm2.pdf}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

[1

] (C:\Users\Remesh\LateX\tex\MISC.DOCS\trial.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1105 strings out of 493921
 12772 string characters out of 3147279
 62446 words of memory out of 3000000
 4449 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3938 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 27i,4n,20p,222b,158s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on trial.pdf (1 page, 870 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 6 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: that means you have used `\usepackage{graphicx}` and it failed to default a driver which means that your tex installation is defective, all tex distributions include graphics.cfg to set up the driver default.

Comment: unrelated to the error but is your pdf file really at the root of your file tree (`/cm2.pdf`)? and `\label` without `\caption` usually does the wrong thing and it is best not to use `[h]` latex usually warns and changes it to `[ht]` but `[htp]` makes it less likely that the figure goes to the end of the document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, the file is really there. Does it mean I will have to modify my tex installation? It was working perfectly before this file!

Comment: no as I say the error is unrelated to any of the code you have shown. You presumably get it on the `\usepackage` line before your document has started. You should fix your example to be the smallest _complete_ document that shows the error and then post that document and the resulting log file. Impossible to debug code that we can not see.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added the MWE and the log file contents

Comment: You somehow have lost miktex's graphics.cfg file Your setup is rather old (2011) so perhaps just update miktex to a current setup but meanwhile using `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}` will get things working again.

Comment: or you could do as it says in the message that you quoted, make a one-line file graphics.cfg that looks like You should make a default driver option in a file 
graphics.cfg
eg: \ExecuteOptions{pdftex}

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, neither is working. It says pdftex.def not found :(

Comment: pdftex.def is part of every tex distribution, you need to update/fix your miktex you could just get pdftex.def from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphics-def but that is papering over the cracks, you should fix your tex installation

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Will I have to reinstall the whole thing or can I just do an update or something?

Comment: No idea, as I say it may be enough just to get that single file, but you may want to check why your miktex is not updating correctly. I do not use miktex so can not help with that much.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I am keeping my fingers crossed because I really don't know the ropes and I have some important work coming up.

Comment: This is some kind of Miktex bug, I'm guessing. The graphicx package used to work for me, until I recently run Miktex's own update, and now I get the exact errors that lexxie reported.

Answer (score 2):

Probably both packages `graphics-cfg` and `graphics-def` are missing. You need to install them using Miktex's (or other) package manager.